# git pull from Github to live server with multiple developers

Tags: git, web, github

I'd like to have a Git setup something like below.

```
Developer 1 --push--> 
                     -->  Github  <--pull-- our server (public www folder)
Developer 2 --push-->
```

The main objective is to keep a copy of our website in a Github repo and let developers pull to the live site when everything looks OK.

So the idea is Developer 1 and 2 can clone the Github repo, make changes locally and push them back.  And when we want to reflect those changes to the live site, it would simply be a matter of running git pull from the public www folder on the server.

I already have a setup like this for my own use, but the server is using my own Github account/key.  This obviously isn't ideal with multiple developers.   So I think a good way might be to simply setup a generic Github account so each developer can simply use that to pull to the live site.

But I can't help but feel like there is a better solution.  Is there a better way; how would you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what deploy keys are for. Have a look at [Managing deploy keys](https://help.github.com/articles/managing-deploy-keys)

Comment: Thanks, this is the kind of solution I was looking for.